# Zip archive on when user clicks submit - CentOS - will zipping operations overlap ever?

Tags: php, zip, centos5

I am building into a function the zipping of a file when the user submits a form.  I'm worried that many userrs may submit the form at one time, and the zip commands would "overlap".  Am I way off base here?  Do I have anything to worry about?  I'm using PHP execute/system command to run things via PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as they're zipping to separate archives, you shouldn't have anything to worry about.